# Changing direction units to km in Navigator for ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-pro, network-analyst, arcgis-navigator, mobile-map-package

I created a road network using ArcMap 10.6 in Projected Coordinate System (PDO_1993_UTM_Zone_40N - meters). I have one travel mode in this network(car). there is no restriction attribute in my road network and i am using length(meters) as default impedance and i have travel time as well. I have defined the driving directions (km) as follows.

```
Directions Configured: Yes
General Directions: 
  Display Length Units: Kilometers
  Length Attribute: Length
  Time Attribute: TimeInMin
Source Directions: 
  Centreline: 
    Street Name Fields: 
      Primary: 
        Name: NAME
        Suffix Type: TYPE
```

Using [Make a Map with your own data](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/navigator/android-tablet/help/make-a-map-with-all-your-own-data.htm#) tutorial I did the following steps:

- I used ArcGIS Pro 2.4 to created a custom basemap
- Added the road network layers to this basemap.
- Created a new map and added this basemap to it.
- Executed the "Create mobile map package" tool to create a package.
- Executed "Share Package" to share it on ArcGIS Online.

Now the issue is when i am using it in Navigator for ArcGIS i am getting a route in miles and i am not finding any option to change it to km.

My main concern is when i create and share the mobile map package i want to use km to be default unit for route.